# If this is heap overflow causing my program to crash, how should I properly handle memory allocation?

Tags: c, debugging, memory-management, file-io, heap-memory

I'm trying to write a program that searches for a pattern in files and replaces them with a some substring. Essentially, I am writing the modified text to a temp file, deleting the original file, and renaming the temp file to the original filename. I had tested this out on single files, one by one, and that seems to work fine.

Next step was to do things recursively, and while it goes over some files, and modifies them as it should, it reaches a point (after a few calls to `replaceline()`) where I get this error.

```
*** Error in `/someplace/a.out': double free or corruption (top): 0x0000000000614090 ***
```

So I want to check things out in gdb, and I am having a hard time understanding:

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007ffff7a4bcc9 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
56      ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007ffff7a4bcc9 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
#1  0x00007ffff7a4f0d8 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00007ffff7a88394 in __libc_message (do_abort=do_abort@entry=1,
    fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff7b96b28 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
#3  0x00007ffff7a9466e in malloc_printerr (ptr=<optimized out>,
    str=0x7ffff7b96c38 "double free or corruption (top)", action=1) at malloc.c:4996
#4  _int_free (av=<optimized out>, p=<optimized out>, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:3840
#5  0x00007ffff7a82ae5 in _IO_new_fclose (fp=0x614090) at iofclose.c:85
#6  0x0000000000400fa8 in replaceline (path=0x7fffffffdff0 "./toast/toast3/tt", patternoo=0x401357 "dime",
    replacearoo=0x401352 "lime") at testrep7.c:91
#7  0x00000000004011c5 in recursiveWalk (pathName=0x7fffffffe440 "./toast/toast3", level=1) at testrep7.c:129
#8  0x000000000040118a in recursiveWalk (pathName=0x40135c "./toast", level=0) at testrep7.c:125
#9  0x000000000040122c in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe958) at testrep7.c:139
(gdb) frame 2
#2  0x00007ffff7a88394 in __libc_message (do_abort=do_abort@entry=1,
    fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff7b96b28 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
175     ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c: No such file or directory.
```

I understand this has something to do with bad memory allocation or not freeing certain pointers? If so, could anyone point out where I should be doing this?

It is also possible that I am deleting a file more than once maybe? This is what I got from looking up what "double free corruption" might mean.

As far as I know, the recursive walk I have is working well, as it outputs exactly what I would want for the path to be used in `replaceline()`.

I decided to include the entire code just in case the error has to do with something outside of `replaceline()` although I do believe that is where things are going wrong. Apologies if there is too much code, but I am not entirely certain that I have managed to pinpoint the problem to certain functions. Thank you.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <libgen.h>

int delete(char* file){

    int status;
    status = remove(file);
}

void renamefile(char* old, char* new){
   int ret;

   ret = rename(old, new);

   if(ret == 0) {
      printf("%s renamed to %s\n", old, new);
   }
   else {
      printf("Error: unable to rename %s\n", old);
        printf("NO %s", strerror(EACCES));
   }
}


char *replace_str(char *str, char *orig, char *rep)
{
  static char buffer[4096];
  char *p;

  if(!(p = strstr(str, orig)))  
    return str;

  strncpy(buffer, str, p-str); 
  buffer[p-str] = '\0';

  sprintf(buffer+(p-str), "%s%s", rep, p+strlen(orig));

  return buffer;
}


void replaceline(char* path, char* patternoo, char* replacearoo){

    char buff[BUFSIZ];      // the input line
    char newbuff[BUFSIZ];   // the results of any editing

   char pattern[200];
    strcpy(pattern, patternoo);

   char replace[200];
    strcpy(replace, replacearoo);

    FILE *in, *out;
     char newstr[200];


    //getbases
    char basec[200];
    char dname[200];
    int found = 0;

    strcpy(basec, path);
    strcpy(dname, dirname(basec));

    strcat(dname, "/loot");

    in = fopen( path, "r" );
    out= fopen( dname, "w" );

    while ( fgets( buff, BUFSIZ, in ) != NULL ) {
        if ( strstr( buff, pattern ) != NULL ) {

             //THIS IS WHERE WE DO THE THING 
                strcpy(newbuff, replace_str(buff, pattern, strcat(replace,pattern)));             
              found = 1;

        } else {
              strcpy( newbuff, buff );
              printf("nothin to do\n");
        }
        fputs( newbuff, out );
            fclose( in );
            fclose( out );
            delete(path); // delete original
            renamefile(dname, path); //the temp is now new
    }

    if(found == 0){ 
    fclose( in );
    fclose( out );
    }
}

void recursiveWalk(const char *pathName, int level) {
   DIR *dir;
   struct dirent *entry;

   if (!(dir = opendir(pathName))) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Could not open directory\n");
      return;
   }

   if (!(entry = readdir(dir))) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Could not read directory\n");
      return;
   }

   do {
      char path[1024];
      int len = snprintf(path, sizeof(path)-1, "%s/%s", pathName, entry->d_name); // get depth
      if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) { // found subdirectory
         // skip hidden paths
         if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0) {
            continue;
         }
         recursiveWalk(path, level + 1);
      }
      else { // files
         fprintf(stdout, "%s \n", path); // HERE!!!!!!!!!!!
            replaceline(path,"dime", "lime");
      }
   } while ((entry = readdir(dir)));

   closedir(dir);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

//  replaceline("./toast/nodime","dime", "lime");
    recursiveWalk("./toast", 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: All I see is "Here is my whole program. Please debug it for me."

Comment: @John3136 I suppose so. At this stage, I really don't know how to do it myself. I'm not that great at C.

Comment: In `replaceline` you have `fclose` calls for the same `FILE` values inside the `while` loop. That means you repeatedly close the same file. Looks like that is what the gdb stack trace is pointing to. Maybe you meant to put that block of code outside the loop?

Comment: Run your program in valgrind, which does a lot of checks and will help you find the cause of your problem.

Comment: @kaylum Thank you, that did it.

Comment: When compiling, always enable all the warnings.  then fix those warnings.  for instance, in the `main()` function signature the parameter `argc` and the parameter `argv` are not used within the body of the function.  Suggest using: `int main( void ){`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) separate code blocks (if, else, for, while, do...while, switch, case, default)  by a blank line.

Comment: the `delete()` function signature says it will return an `int` value.  however: 1) there is no `return value` statement 2) the caller of that function is ignoring the returned value.  Suggest:  `void delete( char* file )
{
    int status;

    if( -1 == (status = remove(file) ) )
    { // then remove failed
        perror( "remove failed" );
    }
}`

Comment: When calling system functions, almost always need to check the returned value to assure the operation was successful, especially regarding functions that modify files or access the stdin stream

Comment: the function `renamefile()` should not assume the problem was `EACCESS`   Suggest using `perror( "rename of file failed" );`

Comment: in the `recursivewalk()` function, the variable `len` is not used.  suggest removing that variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in function: `replaceline()`

I suspect that the code is closing files and deleting the source file way to early.

Suggest read/modify/write in a loop until the end of the file,

then close files and delete the source file.

If the file contains the string to replace then a following pass through the loop will try to read from a closed file.

Suggest not closing, deleting, renaming files until after whole file is read I.E. after exiting the while loop

Comment: Yes, thanks, that is indeed where I was getting the error. I removed the closing of files in the while loop, and left it to to the already existing closing functions outside the loop, with an added flag condition to remove/rename files, as this is what I had originally had in mind when I mistakenly put the closing functions within the loop.